# Makefile condition for compiling one module vs all modules

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cmake

Right for the below makefile i run as "make args=abc" to compile abc. How can i change the condition to run as "make abc" for abc compile and "make all" for everything ? Thanks !

```
modules = \
    abc \
    bfg \
    cyz 

MISC = clean all

all: build

ifdef args
 SUBDIRS="$$args"
else
 SUBDIRS=$(modules)
endif

build:
    for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
    $(MAKE) -C $$dir all; \
    done
```

Comment: Why not use multiple targets for this? So 'make abc' for the module

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `all` target for this.

Use individual targets for each module.

So `make abc` or `make cba` or `make all` depending on what you need to do.

You want something like:

```
modules = \
    abc \
    bfg \
    cyz

.PHONY: all $(modules)

all: $(modules)

$(modules):
    $(MAKE) -C '$@'
```

Comment: What would be the condition for that within makefile ? Thanks !

Comment: Hm? Targets are the main items in makefiles. You would therefore have `.PHONY: abc` and `abc: <main built object of abc module>' and then the rest should be the same. How are were you planning to select just the modules to build with your original idea?

Comment: Edited with actual makefile now. Thank you!